# Sum the values in a pandas column based on the items in another column

Tags: python, pandas

how can I sum the values in column 'two' based on the items in column 'one' in pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Two': [1, 5, 3, 4]})
out[1]:
        One      Two
    0   A         1          
    1   B         5         
    2   A         3               
    3   B         4
```

Expected output should be:

```
A    4
B    9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `group by` the first column and `sum` on the second.

```
df.groupby('One', as_index=False).sum()

  One  Two
0   A    4
1   B    9
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is use pandas built-in functions `.groupby(COLUMN_NAME)` and then `.sum()` that new pandas object

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Two': [1, 5, 3, 4]})

groups = df.groupby('One').sum()
print(groups.head())
```