# add the prices according to the project id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `resource_data`:

```
id      price
p233245 149.00
p069063 14.95
p069063 8.45
p069063 13.59
p069063 24.95
```

and I want to remove duplicates in the id such that one single id contains the addition of the prices, for example, the above should become:

```
id  price
p233245 149.00
p069063 61.94
```

Comment: groupby + sum ? \

Comment: Duplicate of:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953393/sum-the-values-in-a-pandas-column-based-on-the-items-in-another-column). Only groupby and sum functions are enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['p233245', 149.00], ['p069063', 14.95], ['p069063', 8.45]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'price']) 

df.groupby('id').sum()
```

Output:

```
id     price
p069063 23.4
p233245 149.0
```